# How to get magnific popup to work with an array

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to use `$id` from the array `$res[$letter][] = array('id'=> $id, 'title'=> $title);`, to manage magnific popup.

The variable is fetched when I run `print_r($ res);` and therefore also appears when I hover the post on the page, but it does not enable magnific popup by click.

Only the last entry in the extract will activate magnific popup correctly.
If I put the magnific popup link into the while loop, and the skipper foreach loops, it works perfectly, but then I lose this feature and that won’t do.

```
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $res[$letter][] = array('id' => $id, 'titel' => $titel);
}       
foreach($res as $key=>$val)
{
    ?>
    <div class="<?php $letter;?>"></div>
    <?php

    echo "<div class='head_letter'>$key</div>";
    foreach($val as $reqvals) {
        ?>
        <a href="#se_annonce<?php echo $reqvals['id'];?>" class="popup-with-zoom-anim"> //link til popup-vindu
            <div class="boks">
                indhold af boks
            </div>
        </a>

        <?php
    }
}
// this part with magnific popup is inside the statement
<div id="se_annonce<?php echo $reqvals['id'];?>" class="zoom-anim-dialog mfp-hide">
        <div class="titel_pop"><?php echo $reqvals['titel']; ?></div>
</div>
```

What am I not seeing?

Comment: For one you have an extra `'` in your third line in the array - is that in your original code or a typo on stackoverflow?

Comment: I have no clue what you mean. What are you trying to achieve? You say "I lose this feature", which feature? Btw it'd probably help you to translate the variables and such.

Comment: ArSeN: The extra ' in the array is a failure. I have reduced the content of the array and forgot so delete the last '.

Comment: I am guessing you need two parts (link and div) to show each individual popup. Can you explain where the last three lines of your code actually are? Sounds a bit like those should actually be inside the foreach-loop together with the link

Comment: Thats right; two parts. The first link is inside the loop the other was inside the mysqli-statement-but outside the foreach-loop. Now when the last ons is moved inside the foreach-loop, it works. Thanks a hole lot! Well done ArSeN.

Comment: Looks like the Magnific initialization is not binding the action into all the DOM elements. This could be on the javascript side. Try to run manually the Magnific script initialization on your console browser.